# ansible pexpect module with prompt coming on the next line and more than one prompt

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, pexpect

I have a script which prompts me to enter a password twice but the prompt comes on the next line like below:-

`Password:
(I enter the Password here)
Re-enter Password:
(I enter the same Password here)`

I am trying to automate this with Ansible pexpect module and I have something which is not working:-

```
- name: myscript --setup-users
  become: yes
  become_user: someadmin
  expect:
    command: 'myscript --setup-users'
    responses:
      "Password:": "somepassword"
      "Re-enter Password:": "somepassword"
  args:
    chdir: /home/someadmin/
  when:  someuser_out.stdout.find("someuser") == -1
```

I am performing a check to see if the "someuser" is present or not before this play.

This code is not working.

Please help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work with "\r\n".
the code change is as below:-

```
- name: myscript --setup-users
  become: yes
  become_user: someadmin
  expect:
    command: 'myscript --setup-users'
    responses:
      "password:": "somepassword"   #password for first prompt
      "\r\n:": "someotherpassword"  #password for second prompt which comes in the next line
      "\r\n:": "someotherpassword"  #same as above
  args:
    chdir: /home/someadmin/
  when:  someuser_out.stdout.find("someuser") == -1
```